# Looking for simple function: Passes through 0, sqrt like but never reaches 100

Tags: analysis, functions

It's in the title. I am looking for simple function that passes through 0, square root like, never reaches 100, but comes closer and closer to it.

I'm sure this is very basic, nothing fancy. But I don't know it now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "square root-like"? Do you mean that you need it to have infinite slope at $x=0$? Do you want $f(x)\approx \sqrt{x}$ when $x$ is small? Or do you just want a function whose slope decreases and which tends to 100 as $x$ tends to infinity?

Comment: My question aims at: "whose slope decreases and which tends to 100 as x tends to infinity." I am basically trying to give a mathematical impression of a organism that recovers after a shock (0): First very fast, then slower and slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [$ x \mapsto \frac{100}{\pi/2}\arctan  $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28x%29&lk=4&num=1)?

Comment: This function do not expose the vertical tangent at $x=0$ feature of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: I marked this answer as solution because of its simplicity.

Comment: I felt that the vertical tangent is not so important, and he was looking for these 6 characters: $\arctan$

Answer (score 10):

There are infinite solutions to your request, one can be

$$
f(x)=100\frac{\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}
$$